# Using php fetched value in google charts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

It's my first time working with google charts.
I'm using php/mysql to query out results, and then store them in a `div`. I then use `document.getElementByID('field).value` to get it's value and use in the chart.

But somehow, it doesn't seems to be working. What might be the problem ? The output is blank and displays nothing.
All suggestions are welcome.

**php part**

```
include 'dbconnector.php';
include 'class/class.user.php';
$user = new user();
try
{
  $s = $conn->query("SELECT * from messagequeue where indexid=1");
  $s->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $row = $s->fetch();
  $s->closeCursor();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

**HTML Part**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var read = document.getElementById('read').value;
      var unsub = document.getElementById('unsubscribed').value;
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['read',   read],
          ['Unsubscribed',  unsub]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          is3D: true,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="read" id="read" value="<?php echo $row->read; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="unsubscribed" id="unsubscribed" value="<?php echo $row->unsubscribed; ?>">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should try to narrow down where the problem is. Check the generated html and if that is correct / what you are expecting, post that here instead of the php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are getting proper values for `$row->read` & `$row->unsubscribed` then your for html put your js code at the end of body tag like this. It will work.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="read" id="read" value="<?php echo "100" ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="unsubscribed" id="unsubscribed" value="<?php echo "200"; ?>">
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var read = document.getElementById('read').value;
      var unsub = document.getElementById('unsubscribed').value;
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['read',   read],
          ['Unsubscribed',  unsub]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          is3D: true,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, adding the code below the HTML fixed my issue.